# "To date" versus "until now"

Tags: word-choice, expressions, synonyms

Is there a difference between these two expressions? Are they perfect synonyms?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"To date" implies that the current state is unchanged from the previous state, while "until now" implies that it has just changed.  For instance:

> To date, the Foos have never won a game.

Would mean the Foos have not won a game.

> Until now, the Foos never won a game.

Would mean that they just won their first game.

Comment: Yes, this is an important distinction, which however is not obvious to non-native speakers; so you quite often see "until now" from a non-English writer that clearly does not have that intention.

Comment: It might be worth noting that "so far" is a synonym for "to date" in this context: "So far, the Foos have never won a game" also means that the Foos have not won a game. "To date" sounds much more formal to me than "so far"; I associate it with things like newspaper articles, technical reports, and diplomatic correspondence.

Comment: I don't think so. I don't find canonical evidence of this theory.

Answer (score 2):

Those expressions could have slightly different meanings especially when talking about finance.

Compare the statements

> To date, the fund has grown 25% since the start of the year.

versus

> Until now, the fund has grown 25% (since the start of the year?).

*To date* does a good job of conveying the process of tracking the progress. However, *until now* seems to imply that the fund's growth rate has changed, thus our second statement implicitly requires further elaboration. Besides, *until now* and *since the start of the year* don't go well together.

Comment: I interpreted the second statement to mean "The fund has grown 25% per year since it was launched, but the growth rate has recently changed."

Answer (score 0):

When used adverbially before the whole sentence, they have not much difference in some cases. But "to date" can also be used as an adverbial phrase modifying a verb phrase when referring to the present day, while "until now" is not suitable. The Free Dictionary uses such an example:

> How much have you accomplished to date? [correct]
>
> *How much have you accomplished until now? [incorrect]

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question but looking for differences between **to date** and **until now**, I just found this in the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/to_date)

**to date** PHRASE

> Until now.
>
> ‘their finest work to date’

And both are marked as synonyms there.

The accepted answer uses different verb tenses to prove the difference when it seems that both are interchangable.