# “To date” versus “so far”

Tags: word-choice, expressions, synonyms

Are "to date" and "so far" synonyms? Or is there a difference between the two.

For example,

*So far*, research has identified nearly 80 CYP450 enzymes involved in triterpenoid metabolism in plants.

*vs.*

*To date*, research has identified nearly 80 CYP450 enzymes involved in triterpenoid metabolism in plants.

Comment: They are interchangeable. Though, if these are being used in a report of the research, 'To date" is a better lead sentence providing specific results. And, "So far", is better added later to inform of the progress being made.

Comment: Looks like *to date* is more formal than *so far* -- and I do not feel *so far* fits the context at all in the above sentence.

Comment: Related: “To date” versus “until now” https://english.stackexchange.com/q/5948/14666 Note that the accepted answer is only a unsubstantiated opinion, apparently wrong.

Comment: 'To date' suggests to me that the process has been going on for quite a long time - 'up until today's date' - whereas 'so far' could be a long or short timescale - 'I've been looking out of the window for half an hour and haven't seen any birds so far'.

Answer (score -1):

For some reason, I have always liked the phrase “thus far” as it seems somehow more specific to me in certain areas. In my opinion I think it would work with the above sentence example; although “to date” may still be the best choice. Still, I like it, but I try not to use it overly much, as it is more formal sounding.

Still, it depends on what I am saying, and if it needs to maintain a more formal tone.

Comment: I think I see where you're going, but right now it doesn't seem to answer the question as asked.  It feels more like a comment than an answer, especially without any citations.  Could you please expand it a little regarding any differences between "to date" and "so far/thus far"?